# HTML, php, faxing

Tags: php, fax

I want to make a web-page form send that data to the fax number?

any ideas?

Comment: Can you fix the title? should be html.

Comment: One thing for sure: You won't be able to do this in plain PHP. You will need some kind of service for this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you send a fax instead of email?

Comment: I think he's sending messages back to 1987

Answer (score 3):

There are [lots of companies](http://www.google.com/search?q=web+fax+service) that will provide you an API to do this.

It won't be free however.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but google results suggest me those links:

http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice

http://www.send2fax.com/

http://www.programmableweb.com/mashup/send-a-fax-from-php

Let me know if that is helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a commercial service, you could follow the instructions on the Interfax web site to solve your webform-to-fax requirement. Their instructions are summarized here, but visit their "[Web Form to Fax with PHP](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/samples/php/webform-to-fax)" page to get the actual code.

You'll need three parts:

1. **A web form** - a regular HTML form that collects faxing-related fields, such as the recipient name, fax number, and the fax message. Once submitted it calls the web form processing script through the "action" value of the form.
2. **A web form processing script** - it does the following:

   - Holds all settings, such as your InterFAX username and password.
   - Collects values from the web form.
   - Performs error checking on submitted values.
   - Opens a template file (see below) and populates it with values submitted in the form.
   - Submits the populated template file to InterFAX for faxing.
   - Shows the submission result (i.e., not the fax transmission result)
3. **A fax template which gets populated by content entered into the form** - This is where you determine what your fax will look like. You can use HTML and CSS for full page layout control.

Once a visitor fills in the form and clicks "Submit", the inserted values get passed to the form processing script. This script populates the template with these values and submits it to the fax service for processing.  The fax gets sent and you can optionally get an email confirmation once it does.